# g++ : can't link with a main executable file

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, makefile, g++

I'm developing an application using statistical attacks to crack wep keys.

When I compile with my makefile (above) I get this error :

> ld: can't link with a main executable file 'execStatAttack' for
>   architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) make: *** [statAttack] Error 1

My project contain those files :

- statAttack.cpp : contain the main function, uses files above
- rc4.h + rc4.cpp : with those function

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <stdio.h
> #include <vector
>
> #ifndef RC4
> #define RC4
>
> using namespace std
> int* rc4(int);
> int random_byte();
> vector<int> cipher_mess_seq (long, int);
>
> #endif
> ```

- bias.h + bias.cpp :

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <utility>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <string>
>
> #ifndef BIAIS
> #define BIAIS
>
> using namespace std;
>
> typedef pair<int,double> IntegerDoublePair;
> vector<IntegerDoublePair> get_bias (string, int);
> int compareTo (double, double);
> vector<IntegerDoublePair> get_all_biases(string);
>
> #endif
> ```

- and the makefile :

> ```
> CC = g++
> CFLAGS = -Wall -g
> LDFLAGS = -lm 
> EXEC_NAME_NAIVE = execNaiveAttack
> EXEC_NAME_STATALGO = execStatAttack
> OBJ_FILES_NAIVE = naiveAttack.o biais.o rc4.o
> OBJ_FILES_STATALGO = statAttack.o biais.o rc4.o
>
> naiveAttack : $(EXEC_NAME_NAIVE)
>
> statAttack : $(EXEC_NAME_STATALGO)
>
> $(EXEC_NAME_NAIVE) : $(OBJ_FILES_NAIVE)
>    $(CC) $(OBJ_FILES_NAIVE) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC_NAME_NAIVE)
>
> $(EXEC_NAME_STATALGO) : $(OBJ_FILES_STATALGO)
>    $(CC) $(OBJ_FILES_STATALGO) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC_NAME_STATALGO)
>
> %.o : %.cpp
>    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
>
> clean :
>    rm -f $(OBJ_FILES_NAIVE) $(OBJ_FILES_STATALGO)
>
> mrproper: clean
>    rm -rf $(EXEC_NAME_NAIVE) $(EXEC_NAME_STATALGO)
> ```

this is my configuration (terminal) :

> ==> g++ --version
>
> Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>
> Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
>
> Thread model: posix

So i would like your help, to find out why this error appeared.

Thanks.

Comment: You have several typos in your source files, e.g. `#include <vector` and `using namespace std` - you will need to fix these and any other similar mistakes to have a chance of compiling the code.

Comment: You should also probably stick to spelling `bias` `bias` instead of also using `biais` in some places. Is there more to the error than what you pasted?

Comment: thank you for responding @EtanReisner.
these errors are not really in the files, copy mistakes. i've changed also **biais (french spelling)** by **bias**.
but the thing is that, i can compile the project and get working executable file.
i forgot to mention that this error is in OS X, and on linux i have another kind of error : too long to copy it here. but it compiles.

Comment: I finally founded the error, it was in my makefile, those lines
**naiveAttack : $(EXEC_NAME_NAIVE)
**statAttack : $(EXEC_NAME_STATALGO)
because the executable was already generated, and another compilation was done after, so it generates this error, for more informations i can provide the new makefile, for those who has this type of error.
thank you for help. PEACE !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error usually means you're missing a `-c` when compiling a simple program, something like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
Program: main.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

What's happening is that the first rule is building `main.o` just like you asked, but instead of being an object file, it's actually the complete, compiled and linked program.

When the second rule tries to use it as an object file, the linker finds that it's not an object file at all and produces "can't link with a main executable file."

Obviously for a more complex program, one with multiple object files or with library dependencies, it would not be able to build an executable from just the one source file, so you'll get a different error and never get as far as the link rule.

The solution, of course, is to add `-c` to the first rule so that the first invocation only compiles and does not link, producing an actual object file.

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Paul R Wrote:

> You have several typos in your source files, e.g. `#include <vector` and `using namespace std` - you will need to fix these and any other similar mistakes to have a chance of compiling the code.

@Etan Reisner wrote:

> You should also probably stick to spelling `bias` `bias` instead of also using `biais` in some places.

The OP wrote:

> I finally found the error, it was in my makefile, those lines:
>    `naiveAttack : $(EXEC_NAME_NAIVE) 
>   statAttack : $(EXEC_NAME_STATALGO)`
>    because the executable was already generated, and another compilation was done after, so it generates this error, for more informations I can provide the new makefile, for those who have this type of error.